# Calling DLL with a C interface from Java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I'm attempting to call native methods within a 3rd party DLL, which has a C interface with methods such as:

```
DWORD ExampleInterfaceMethod( DWORD Mode, LPSTR Header );
```

I've successfully loaded the DLL using:

```
System.loadLibrary("DLLName");
```

and I've created a method:

```
protected native int ExampleInterfaceMethod(int type, int Nth, byte[] name);
```

This method doesn't seem to be using the correct variable types, as whenever I call it the following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.DLLTest.ExampleInterfaceMethod(II[B)I
```

What variable types do I need to use in Java in order to call this method, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Have you gone through any of the other steps to first create your jni bridge c program such as using javah to help create your header file and then create the c or cpp file that corresponds to the header file?  If not, then you'd better read up first on using JNI to allow Java to call native code. For my money though, if the native code is from C and not CPP, I'd use JNA, not JNI since I find it easier.

Comment: Is there any way to create this header file through myEclipse? I'm hoping that there is a way to create the header file dynamically.

I'm actually not really sure what I need to do in order to accomplish this. Are there any good step by step tutorials in order to do this, I can't seem to find any that discuss exactly what I want to do here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Create the header files dynamically?? That doesn't make any sense to me. Are you trying to build your own compiler?  It sounds to me as if you haven't yet googled JNI, JNA or their related tutorials, and I suggest you do so before going further. This will take some effort and time on your part but is well worth your while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JNI, you need specially-named C functions to implement your Java `native` methods. You can't simply add a `native` method to call an existing C function - instead the normal way is creating a "wrapper" C function which calls the existing one, and is named the right way.

You might want to have a look at [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna). This is a wrapper around JNI which allows you to call C functions from the Java side without manually writing adapting native code for this.